# Export to Pentaho Report results to csv or excel

Tags: excel, csv, reporting-services, pentaho

I'm generating static HTML reports through Pentaho's integration tool.  I'm developing the reports in Pentaho report designer.  My reports have several rows of data which when viewed on the BI server can be exported to csv or excel.  I'm looking for that same functionality built into my prpt reports using the report designer.  My reports will be viewed separately from the BI server but the user must still have the ability to export the results.  I have been unsuccessful in finding any resources for Pentaho Report Designer and CTools are not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use input-excel from Pentaho PDI. You should generate a transformation where you put three steps.

1. Input Table. Here you put the query.
2. Copy rows to result. It's a step that you can find on the section *Steps* > *Job* > *Copy rows to result*.
3. *Steps > Output > Microsoft Excel Writter*.